# Bulk Add SmtpAddress to users Exchange 2010

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server-2010

We just recently added a domain to our accepted domains and e-mail address policy. While many of our users follow that policy, we have a third domain that some users have as their primary address that does not follow an address policy. I need to take those users and add an SMTP Address in the format of `firstname.lastname@domain2.com`.

E.g., john.doe@domain3.com (primary) has john.doe@domain1.com as an alias and needs to have john.doe@domain2.com added as an SMTP Address.

I have the following code but am receiving errors:

```
$Users = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object {($_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*domain3.com*)}
foreach ($a in $Users) {
    $b = Get-User $a.Primary.SMTPAddress
    $a.EmailAddresses.Add("$($b.Firstname + "." + $b.Lastname)@domain2.com")
}
$Users |%{Set-Mailbox $_.PrimarySMTPAddress -EmailAddresses $_.EmailAddresses
```

Errors are as follows:

`Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "john.doe@domain3.com" value of type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.UserIdParameter".
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-User], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-User`

`Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "The address '.@domain2.com' is invalid: ".@domain2.com" isn't a valid SMTP address. The domain name can't contain spaces and it has to have a prefix and a suffix, such as example.com."
At C:\_scripts\SmtpAdd.ps1:4 char:23
+     $a.emailaddresses.Add <<<< ("$($b.Firstname + "." + $b.LastName)@domain2.com")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

`Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "john.due@domain3.com" value of type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-Mailbox`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem starts with this line:

`$b = Get-User $a.Primary.SMTPAddress`

`Get-User` fails to return a valid user as `$a.Primary.SMTPAddress` doesn't return a type that `Get-User` can use. That then causes `EmailAddresses.Add` to fail as `$b` is null. `Set-Mailbox` fails for the same reason as `Get-User`

Try this instead (you'll also need to do this on the `Set-Mailbox` line):

`$b = Get-User $a.Primary.SMTPAddress.ToString()`

Comment: This worked when specifying a single user with `$Users = Get-Mailbox "User Name". I still receive the "Exception calling "Add" error that is listed above with the same code in OP.

Comment: Can you examine the contents of $b before you do the `EmailAddresses.Add`?

Comment: The issue appeared to have stemmed from a separate issue with our Exchange environment. That has since been fixed and the script ran. Thanks again @Tav.